# Nginx configuration; Call api in other container gives 405 error

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a React project which is in a docker container. The application is built and is running on Nginx. As it is shown in the following docker-compose file this React application can call `api` container

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  # UI Container spec. note that 'ui' is the name of the container internally (also 'container_name')
  ui:
    container_name: ps-ui-prod
    image: ps-ui-prod
    build:
      context: ./UI
      dockerfile: DockerFile_UI.prod    
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    

  # Database Container spec.
  sql:
    container_name: ps-sql
    image: ps-sql
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
      SA_PASSWORD: 'Pa55w0rd'
    build:
      context: ./DockerDB
      dockerfile: DockerFile_SQL
    ports:
      - 1633:1433 # Map 1433 from inside the container to 1633 host to avoid port conflict with local install

  # API container spec.
  api:
    container_name: ps-api
    image: ps-api
    build:
      context: ./Api
      dockerfile: DockerFile_API
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:5555
    ports:
        - "5555:5555"
```

The IP address of `api` container is:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ps-api      
    172.21.0.3
```

Also the proxy of react application is set to `"proxy": "http://api:5555",`
The Nginx configuration file is as below:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

I know that I should add configurations to handle POST requests but I do not know how to do that when the POST address is a container. Moreover, I should say that all the three containers can ping each other:

[image]

The problem is when I call the `api` the browser returns 405 error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proxy your graphql requests to your API backend, e.g., add the following to your nginx configuration server block (the UI service in your case):

```
location /api/graphql {
    proxy_pass http://api:5555/api/graphql;
}
```

This will probably fix the problem for the requests that are sent to the `/api/graphql` endpoint. I suppose the same issue exists for all requests to the `/api` endpoint. If this is the case you might want to proxy all `/api` requests by removing `/graphql` part from the above snippet.